# how to make a post request to odoo controller from outside odoo?

Tags: python, jquery, ajax, odoo

i am trying to get a form to ouside odoo so i built the form with website builder  [html_form_builder](https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/11.0/html_form_builder/)
i generated the code of html by the module
the form generated with action attribute

```
<form id="odoo_form" method="POST" action="http://localhost:8069/form/insert" enctype="multipart/form-data">
....
</form>
```

i extended the html with jquery code

```
$.ajax(my_form.attr('action'), {
            data: postData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            headers: {"Accept": "application/json" ,
            }, 
            success: function(data) {
                                    //alert('response data = ' + data);
                                    console.log('Success'); 
                                },
                                error: function (data) {
                                },
    type: 'POST'});
```

when you call jquery code 
the controller will be invoked

```
@http.route('/form/insert', type="http", auth="public", csrf=False)
    def my_insert(self, **kwargs):
        return self.process_form(kwargs)
```

the process_form will as expected

```
if form_error:
    return json.JSONEncoder().encode({'status': 'error', 'errors': return_errors})
```

i have seen the log the function invoked and make return /
but i get this error in jquery

```
POST https://localhost:8069/form/insert net::ERR_FAILED
```

Comment: What is the form of your json ? And you called your url with header JSON. You should change the type of http.route by json.

Comment: i have solved it @jo541 see answer below. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved the problem by editing controller function

```
    @http.route('/form/insert', type="http", auth="public", csrf=False)
    def my_insert(self, **kwargs):
        body = self.process_form(kwargs)
        return request.make_response(body,{
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':  '*',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET',
            })
```